# Create a new data frame column that is a combination of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 columns a , b ,c and I want to combine them into a new column with the help of column mood as the following :

if mod= 1 , data from a

if mod=2 , data from b

if mode=3, data from c

example

```
    mode     a     b      c
      1      2     3      4
      1      5     53    14
      3      2     31    24
      2      12    13    44
      1      20    30     40
```

Output

```
    mode     a     b      c       combine
      1      2     3      4          2
      1      5     53    14          5
      3      2     31    24          24
      2      12    13    44          13
      1      20    30     40         20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the row/column indexing to get the values from the dataset.  Here, the row sequence (`seq_len(nrow(df1))`) and the column index ('mode') are `cbind`ed to create a `matrix` to extract the corresponding values from the subset of dataset

```
df1$combine <- df1[2:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$mode)]
df1$combine
#[1]  2  5 24 13 20
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(mode = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), a = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 
12L, 20L), b = c(3L, 53L, 31L, 13L, 30L), c = c(4L, 14L, 24L, 
44L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: how about if the number of numbers in mode is larger than the columns whose we want to combine?

Comment: @sherek_66. You meant if the columns doesn't exist? .  If that is the case, create a condition `i1  <- df1$mode <= ncol(df1)`, then use that index for subssetting i..e `df1$combine[i1] <- df1[i1, 2:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$mode)[i1, ]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in base R that works by converting "mode" to letters then extracting those values in the matching columns.

```
df1$combine <- diag(as.matrix(df1[, letters[df1$mode]]))
```

Also, two ways with `dplyr()`. Nested `if_else` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
   mutate(combine = 
       if_else(mode == 1, a, 
            if_else(mode == 2, b, c)
            )
       )
```

And `case_when()`:

```
df1 %>% mutate(combine = 
   case_when(mode == 1 ~ a, mode == 2 ~ b, mode == 3 ~ c)
   )
```